# GAE JDO: default fetch group member null on second read

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have a persistable class like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private Set<Key> mySet = new HashSet<Key>(); 
    ...
}
```

Which I first persist and then read back like so:

```
pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup(FetchPlan.DEFAULT);
pm.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth(1);
myInstance = pm.getObjectById(MyClass.class, key);
```

What's bizarre is that this works fine the first time after a server restart. However, the second time I make the query, mySet remains null.

I have been trying the same with an ArrayList, but no luck. I'm completely clueless as to what might cause behaviour like this, so any vague pointers as to what may be the cause would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I found a fix, but I don't understand why it works. If I add a copy constructor for User and copy the instance after the read, it works consistently. I would assume that there's a cache that always hands me back the same instance, but stepping through the program, I can't find any code that would set roles to null. Is this likely to be a side effect I'm overlooking or is there a more fundamental issue that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I should also note that using the datastore viewer, I can see that the data has not changed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of 'key' hasn't changed in the interim?

Comment: So what state is the object in after getObjectById ? JDOHelper.getObjectState(obj) tells you, as does the log. What state is the object in when you try to access its field? The log tells you way more, and referring to it is the way. Also state the version of the GAE JDO plugin you're using (1.0.10? 2.0.1?, 2.1.1?)